# I don't seem to get how the loop is working so that the answer is 55, how the increment is being done?

Tags: javascript

This is the actual code from the book Eloquent Javascript:

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 10) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}
console.log(total) 55
```

Under are the things that I tried so I could understand but it all seems too weird for me.

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 1) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}
console.log(total) 1
```

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 2) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}
console.log(total) 3
```

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 3) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}
console.log(total) 6
```

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 4) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}
console.log(total) 10
```

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 5) {
  total += count;
  count += 1;
}
console.log(total) 15
```

Can someone tell me how this is working bc I don't get it?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the code?

Comment: If you just add a console.log for the count and the total for each step of the iteration it should be quite simple to understand what's happening.

Comment: Counts gets one added to itself each time, but total get count added to itself each time. I think total could be called a triangular number.

Comment: The code is calculating [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). in your case it's the 10th triangular number which is 55.

Answer (score 2):

Follow it through with pencil and paper (or the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser):

- `total` starts at 0
- `count` starts at 1
- The loop continues as long as `count <= 10` is true
- On each loop iteration

  - `total`'s value is *increased* by `count`. (`value += count` is basically `total = total + count`).
  - `count` is increased by 1.

    So the first time, `total` (0) + `count` (1) = 1, which is put back in `total`. The second time, `total` (1) + `count` (2) = 3, which is put back in `total`. Etc.

If you follow it through until `count` is 11, you'll see you get 55 in `total`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't understand that the total was being stored each time. Huge help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a confusing example, but we can step through it. As you can guess when the while loop ends, the variable `count` will have the value 11. However `total` is equal to 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55. Every time the loop runs the `count` value will be added to the `total` value.

Try to run this code and understand each print statement:

```
var total = 0;
var count = 1;
while (count <= 10) {
  console.log(total)
  console.log(count)
  total += count;
  count += 1;
  console.log(count)
  console.log(total)
}
console.log(total)
```

Comment: Wow, you Sir just showed me a new way to debug these stuff, much appreciated.

Comment: A print statement is the simplest way to debug. I’m not sure what program you’re using to code. But there are actual debuggers, that will help you step through the code. But I would understand the basics of programming before going into how to debug with a debugger! Add as many print statement as you need!

Answer (score 0):

you're doing
    total += count
which is the same as
    total = total + count

You're then doing
    count += 1
which is the same as
    count = count + 1

What you're essentially doing is a cumulative count. Total = 0, then total = 1 + 0, then total = 2 + 1 + 0... all the way up to 10 + 9 + 8... + 1 + 0 which is 55.